# Microsoft Graph API: Is there a way to get the user's acitivity feed of teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We want to get the number of acitivities for a user, which is also shown as badge in the teams app.
I didn't found any direct way. Does anyone found a way to achieve this indirectly?

Comment: Do you mean activity feed for an user ?

Comment: yes :-) @Subhasish-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way to get all the activity of an user in Teams.

You can look into [Subscription Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0). It allows a client app to receive change notifications about changes to data in Microsoft Graph. Currently, subscriptions are enabled for the following resources:

- An alert from the Microsoft Graph Security API
- A conversation in an Office 365 group
- Content in the hierarchy of a root folder driveItem
  in OneDrive for Business, or of a root folder or subfolder driveItem
  in a user's personal OneDrive
- A list under a SharePoint site
- A message, event, or contact in Outlook
- A user or group in Azure Active Directory

See [Use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) for the possible resource path values for each supported resource.